# Firewall: allow all traffic from sources authenticated via. an open ssh connection

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, unix

I'm looking for a way to avoid the editing of the firewall rules all the time on test and dev servers. I don't want to open up all ports. So I thought maybe there is a way to allow all traffic from sources with an established ssh connection automatically. (Years back someone told me they did it like this for dev/test servers -> no root and firewall editing required and applications don't need to be secured)

I know I could use an ssh tunnel, but the issue with this is with dynamic port applications, multi port applications and the sheer overhead of work.

IpTables and other firewalls probably don't know if an ssh connection was authenticated but is there maybe a work around or alternative? (e.g. established for more than 5 seconds -> pub/private key auto disconnect on fail)

- INPUT DROP
- ALLOW LOOPBACK
- ALLOW SSH
- ALLOW LOCAL NETWORK
- ALLOW all traffic from sources with an established ssh connection.

All the rules are straight forward besides the last one. Unfortunately I don't have contact information of the person I once talked to about it and i couldn't dig anything related/similar up within a good hour of research.

Is something like this even possible? I appreciate any input :)

Comment: I know there's an IPTable command to allow all established sessions, but that's technically firewall editing

Comment: @MichaelBailey you made me curios, whats the command you are talking about?

Comment: iptables –A OUTPUT –p tcp --sport 22 –m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED –j ACCEPT @SuperUser for outbound traffic

Comment: @MichaelBailey would this also allow traffic not related to the ssh tunnel? Editing the firewall is fine, I just don't want to do it all the time and I don't want colleges to wait for someone with the privileges.

Comment: It'll only do sport 22 so port 22 so SSH. I bet that command can be tweaked for other use-cases however.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably bend 'fail2ban' to your desires, using a custom filter to detect *successful* logins, and a custom action to add iptables rules for the detected source IP rather than banning them.

It's a bit odd so you'd want some really good comments in your configuration for the next person coming along to be able to understand what on earth you were doing :)

Comment: Sounds like a good way. I'll ask a college on his opinion about it and do some research. Thank you :)

Comment: So I have done some more research and came across this neat way of hooking sshd. For me it feels a bit more safe, and especially more lightweight than using a third party log watcher like fail2ban or ossec. Do you see any down sight about this, as I'm not quite experienced with this type of stuff.